# accessing react state variable outside of a function in a component is printing null

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-state-management

I have a `AutoHospitals` component and I am trying to get the value of a state variable outside the `.then` function but it is printing `null`.

Here is the code snippet where `this.state.retrievedmrnNumber` is printing.

```
.then(response => {
        console.log("Extracting mrnNumber from Hospitals API results")
        console.log(response.data.mrnNumber);
        let  retrievedMrnNo = response.data.mrnNumber;
        this.setState({ retrievedmrnNumber: retrievedMrnNo});
        console.log("Printing Retrieved mrn number from state");
        console.log(this.state.retrievedmrnNumber);
    })
```

Here is the console log statements outside the above `.then` function, where it is printing null:

```
console.log("Outside of then function: Printing Retrieved mrn number from state");
console.log(this.state.retrievedmrnNumber);
```

How do I access it outside of `.then` function?My ultimate goal is to use the value on this line:

```
selectedHospitals = [{label: this.props.value[0] && this.state.retrievedmrnNumber || 'Select'}]
```

**Full component code is below:**

```
export class AutoHospitals extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
       
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            selectedHospitalValues: null,
            selectedHospitals: [],
            retrievedmrnNumber:null,
            loading: false
        };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
     
       
    }

   onChange = (val) => {
       

        this.setState({
            value: val,
            selectedHospitalValues: val
        });
        this.props.onChange(val)
    };

    fetchRecords() {
        
        let url = 'myurl'
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        });       

        return axios
             .get(url)
             .then(response => {

                              
                let selectedHospitals;
               
                if(this.props.value[0]){
                        console.log('this.props.value is DEFINED - Request has been EDITED!!!!')

                        // START: Logic to get MRN Number 
                      
                        let hospitalIdtoRetrieveMRNNumber = this.props.value[0].hospitalId;

                        axios
                        .get('api/Hospitalses/'+hospitalIdtoRetrieveMRNNumber)
                        .then(response => {
                            console.log("Extracting mrnNumber from Hospitals API results")
                            console.log(response.data.mrnNumber);
                            let  retrievedMrnNo = response.data.mrnNumber;
                            this.setState({ retrievedmrnNumber: retrievedMrnNo});
                            console.log("Printing Retrieved mrn number from state");
                            console.log(this.state.retrievedmrnNumber);

                        
                        
                         })   
                         // END: Logic to get mrn Number 
                         console.log("Outside response block: Printing Retrieved mrn number from state");
                         console.log(this.state.retrievedmrnNumber);
                       
                        selectedHospitals = [{label: this.props.value[0] && this.state.retrievedmrnNumber || 'Select'}]
                         //let selectedHospitals = [{label: this.props.value[0] && 'mrn # 1234' || 'Select'}]

                }else {
                    console.log('this.props.value is UNDEFINED - it is a NEW  REQUEST');
                }
                this.setState({
                    loading: false
                });       
                if (this.props.value) {
                    this.props.value.forEach(e => {
                        selectedHospitals.push(response.data._embedded.Hospitalses.filter(hospitalSet => {
                          
                            return hospitalSet.hospitalId === e.hospitalId
                        })[0])
                    })
                }

              
              
                

            this.setState({

                  
                selectedHospitals: response.data._embedded.Hospitalses.map(item => ({
                   label: (item.mrnNumber.toString()),
                        projectTitle: item.projectTitle,
                        hospitalId: item.hospitalId,
                    })),                    
                    selectedHospitalsValues: selectedHospitals
                });
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));

            
          

    }

    


    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchRecords(0)
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <Hospitalselect value={this.state.selectedHospitalsValues} options={this.state.selectedHospitals} onChange={this.onChange } optionHeight={60} /> 
                <div className="sweet-loading" style={{ marginTop: '-35px' }}>
                    <ClockLoader
                        css={override}
                        size={30}
                        color={"#123abc"}
                        loading={this.state.loading}
                    />
                </div>               
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: look at the docs ... [the state updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: @Codenewbie Can you point out exactly which section in the doc is applicable in my case? I looked at the `Do Not Modify State Directly` section and that looks correct in my case.

Comment: i was pointing at this code `this.setState({ retrievedmrnNumber: retrievedMrnNo});` ... this can be async ... so logging it right away after setting may not work as expected

Comment: So how would you suggest to fix this? I tried testing the console log in `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){}` and it did show the value here but I want it at this line ` selectedHospitals = [{label: this.props.value[0] && this.state.retrievedmrnNumber || 'Select'}]
`

Comment: I would write that as `{label: (this.props.value[0] && this.state.retrievedmrnNumber) || 'Select'}` but is it boolean after all you need in `selectedHospitals` ? It's not clear what you need to check

Comment: Yeah, but `this.state.retrievedmrnNumber` is not available outside the `then` function  and hence I am unable to use it as you suggested here`selectedHospitals = [{label: this.props.value[0] && this.state.retrievedmrnNumber || 'Select'}]1

Comment: can you attach a codepen or sandbox ,would be easy to fix ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Promise from the async axios.get function hasn't resolved by the time you call the state value in selectedHospitals

Try passing a callback function to the return of the then statement:

```
.then(response => {
    console.log("Extracting mrnNumber from Hospitals API results")
    console.log(response.data.mrnNumber);
    handleRequest(response.data.mrnNumber);
    console.log("Printing Retrieved mrn number from state");
    console.log(this.state.retrievedmrnNumber);
})
```

And here is the callback which can use setState:

```
    handleRequest(data) {
        this.setState({ retrievedmrnNumber: data});
}
```

**EDIT** To bind handle request to this properly try making it an arrow function:

```
 handleRequest = (data) => this.setState({retrievedmrnNumber:data});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing this and for some reason I keep on getting `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: handleRequest is not defined` even though I included ` this.handleRequest = this.handleRequest.bind(this);` in constructor.

Comment: Hey good catch. Just edited my above response. Try that.

Comment: Hey, So you want me to define `handleRequest = (data) => this.setState({retrievedmrnNumber:data});` inside `.then` function?

Answer (score 0):

It's all about sync\async. Consider following two examples:

With `then` which is fully async (and do not allowing any waits) :

```
export const download = (url, filename) => {
    fetch(url, {
        mode: 'no-cors' 
        /*
        * ALTERNATIVE MODE {
        mode: 'cors'
        }
        *
        */
    }).then((transfer) => {
        return transfer.blob();                // RETURN DATA TRANSFERED AS BLOB
    }).then((bytes) => {
        let elm = document.createElement('a');  // CREATE A LINK ELEMENT IN DOM
        elm.href = URL.createObjectURL(bytes);  // SET LINK ELEMENTS CONTENTS
        elm.setAttribute('download', filename); // SET ELEMENT CREATED 'ATTRIBUTE' TO DOWNLOAD, FILENAME PARAM AUTOMATICALLY
        elm.click();                             // TRIGGER ELEMENT TO DOWNLOAD
        elm.remove();
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);                     // OUTPUT ERRORS, SUCH AS CORS WHEN TESTING NON LOCALLY
    })
}
```

With `await`, where the response becomes sync:

```
export const download = async (url, filename) => {
    let response = await fetch(url, {
        mode: 'no-cors' 
        /*
        * ALTERNATIVE MODE {
        mode: 'cors'
        }
        *
        */  
    }); 
    try {
        let data = await response.blob();
        let elm = document.createElement('a');  // CREATE A LINK ELEMENT IN DOM
        elm.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);  // SET LINK ELEMENTS CONTENTS
        elm.setAttribute('download', filename); // SET ELEMENT CREATED 'ATTRIBUTE' TO DOWNLOAD, FILENAME PARAM AUTOMATICALLY
        elm.click();                             // TRIGGER ELEMENT TO DOWNLOAD
        elm.remove();
    } 
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }   
}
```

The await example can be called as anonymous function (hope the normal call also possible):

```
(async () => {
                await download('/api/hrreportbyhours',"Report "+getDDMMYYY(new Date())+".xlsx");    
                await setBtnLoad1(false);
            })();
```

Comment: Can you relate your example with my post and answer it in my context? Thanks !